# Retrieving the name of the file that is associated with a file pointer

Tags: c, file, pointers

Assume I have a file pointer `FILE* myfile`. Is there a way to retrieve the name of the file where `myfile` is reading from or writing to?

Comment: In short there is no way to do so as that is runtime/os implementation defined and no standard function call to achieve this...

Comment: What is the file name of `stdin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in any CRT implementation that I've ever seen.  It is useless info, you already have to supply the file name to get a FILE*.  You could probably dig an operating system handle out of the FILE structure although you might need to hop through a file descriptor table.  Your next problem is then the operating system support you'd need to map a file handle back to a file name.  That should be difficult too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice example that uses an overwritten struct MyFile:
[How to get filename from a FILE*](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-179423.html)